# Failure of a twofold call of a function containing a cudaDeviceReset() invocation

Tags: matrix, cuda

I have the following function

```
void dummy() {
    cusolverDnHandle_t cudenseH;
    cusolverStatus_t cusolver_status = cusolverDnCreate(&cudenseH); 
    checkStatus(cusolver_status);

    cusolverDnDestroy(cudenseH); 
    cudaDeviceReset(); 
}
```

If I call this function twice, `checkStatus` will fail on the second call, while testing the result of `cusolverDnCreate(&cudenseH);`.

Comment: I think the problem is due to the call to `cudaDeviceReset()` which resets the status of the driver. If you re-initialize the device with `cudaFree(0)` between the two `dummy()` calls, the second call does not fail anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to the use of `cudaDeviceReset()` at the end of the `dummy()` function which resets the status of the driver. Before the second call to `dummy()`, you need to re-initialize the device. A typical way to initialize the device is to use `cudaFree(0)`.

This is a working version of your code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_paraMeters.h"

#include<stdio.h>

#include <cusolverDn.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

#include "Utilities.cuh"

void dummy() {
    cusolverDnHandle_t cudenseH;
    cusolverStatus_t cusolver_status = cusolverDnCreate(&cudenseH); 
    cusolveSafeCall(cusolver_status);

    cusolverDnDestroy(cudenseH); 
    cudaDeviceReset(); 
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main(){

    printf("First call\n");
    dummy();
    cudaFree(0);
    printf("Second call\n");
    dummy();

    return 0;
}
```

The `Utilities.cu` and `Utilities.cuh` files are mantained [here](https://github.com/OrangeOwlSolutions/CUDA_Utilities) and omitted.